# Display RecyclerView Items In Row/Inline

Tags: android

Here's what I want to achieve:
[image: RecyclerView]

I've created a RecyclerView displaying some items. Those are perfectly displayed one item in a row, but what if I want to display them like the image. GridView can be option to show some items per row but what if I want to achieve something like the image? e.g display the words if it fits in the row, otherwise in the next row.

Here's the LinearLayout I'm using to display the items of RecyclerView. It displays one item in a row.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@drawable/tags_results"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tagoutput"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="7dp"
    android:text="awesome video tag here"
    android:gravity="left|center"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
    ></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should use [chips](https://material.io/components/chips#input-chips) instead of RecyclerView

Comment: thanks a lot, so I can also set the chip items using Volley!